# How to add ( integrate ) crawljax with crawler4j?

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers, crawler4j

I am working on web crawler which fetch data form website using crawler4j and everything goes well but the main problem is with ajax-based events . So, I found crawljax library does this matter but I couldn't where and when to use it .

When have I use it ( I mean work sequences )?

- before fetching page using crawler4j.

Or

- after fetching page using crawler4j.

Or

- have I use url coming using crawler4j and use it to fetch Ajax data (page) using crawljax.

Answer (score 1):

The library [crawljax](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax) is basically a crawler for its own purpose. Integration into `crawler4j` requires a lot of manual effort on your side.

I recommend, that you use a combination  of [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) and/or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) and/or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) in front of `crawler4j`, i.e. you could run the JavaScript engine as a Proxy in front of `crawler4j`. However, this will slow down the performance of your web-crawleer